# How to check if xcache is installed properly?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, zend-framework, xcache

I've installed xcache on a LEMP setting using the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/src && wget https://xcache.lighttpd.net/pub/Releases/3.2.0/xcache-3.2.0.tar.gz && tar -xzf xcache-3.2.0.tar.gz && cd xcache-3.2.0

phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --enable-xcache --enable-xcache-optimizer --enable-xcache-coverager && make && make install
```

It worked and finally showed:

Installing shared extensions: `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/`

Then I added the following to `php.ini`

```
[xcache]
extension = " /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xcache.so"
xcache.admin.user = ""
xcache.admin.pass       = ""
xcache.admin.enable_auth = Off
xcache.test = Off
xcache.coredump_directory = ""
xcache.shm_scheme = mmap
xcache.cacher = On
xcache.size = 1024M
xcache.count = 8
xcache.slots = 8K
xcache.ttl = 0
xcache.gc_interval = 0
xcache.var_size = 32M
xcache.var_count = 1
xcache.var_slots = 8K
xcache.var_ttl = 0
xcache.var_maxttl = 0
xcache.var_gc_interval = 300
xcache.mmap_path = "/dev/zero"
xcache.optimizer = Off
xcache.coverager = Off
xcache.coveragedump_directory = ""
xcache.stat     = Off
xcache.readonly_protection = Off
```

But when I check `php -v` all I can't see xcache. All I can see is:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli) (built: Jul 28 2016 19:31:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

What am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Comment: `php -i | grep xcache`

Comment: And do not forget to restart required services (nginx, php-fpm).

Comment: `php -i | grep xcache` shows nothing. Also I've restarted `php5-fpm` and `nginx`

Comment: it is not installed correctly

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-xcache` ?

Comment: I used the first 2 commands to install because I read online that `php5-xcache` installs an older version of `xcache` If I run `sudo apt-get install php5-xcache` now, will it be a problem?

Comment: It might be older but configured, tested and compatible for your distribution!  ;) Do you need any features from that new version? If not do not waste effort. "Bleeding edge"  called bleeding for a reason ;)

Comment: So shall I run the `sudo apt-get install php5-xcache` now. Will it cause any issue?

Comment: Should not. Try it you can always run `sudo apt-get purge php5-xcache` ;) Do not forget to restart services

Comment: I just ran the command, but now what should this line be? `extension = " /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xcache.so"`

Comment: I think you can just delete whole section as if you have Ubuntu or Debian it would create xcache.ini

Comment: where can I find the xcache.ini file?

Comment: If it does not work `extension=xcache.so` - should work

Comment: Depends on distro `/etc/php5/mods-available` for me. It can be some other folder in `/etc/php5`

Comment: `/etc/php5/cli|apache2|fpm/conf.d` usualy just have symlinks

Comment: Found it, it's under `mods-available` for me too.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks a lot @E_p. You're the man!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just not to keep question without answer posting our discussion here:

To install xcache use version distributed with your linux

For **Debian**/**Ubuntu**

`> sudo apt-get install php5-xcache`

Why would you use outdated version of some (php extension) package?

1. Maintained by community
2. Tested
3. 100% compatible with your version of PHP
4. Configured - No need to edit your config

If you 100% need to get a package that is not in repo use try to use `pecl`.

`>sudo pecl install package`

`Pecl` does make package for you almost same way as if you would build it yourself. But it allows you easier management and updates.

So and the very last choice would be make it yourself. (Only do it if there is 100% need for a package). Worst option as you lose any level of management and need to maintain and upgrade package 100% yourself.

#### `3rd party PPAs` - For security reasons I would never install package form any external 3rd party PPA to a production server.

And one more thing pecl/self make would require you to install build tools on your machine. It uses lots of space and potentially might increase security risks for production server. So as an option create a VM copy of production server do a build/pecl on it, then just copy compiled library to your production server.